# Vue dynamic query key

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router

I wanna make url with choosen settings

```
const settings = this.getSettings();//returns object
Object.entries(settings).forEach(([key, value]) => {
       this.$router.push({ query: { ...this.$route.query, key: value } }); //why i can't access key here?
});
```

Comment: The "key" in forEach table argument is a variable, while the "key" inside the object below is an object property named "key"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the key by `[]` accessor :

```
this.$router.push({ query: { ...this.$route.query, [key]: value } });
```

Answer (score 1):

just a guess: "key" in query: { ...this.$route.query, key: value } will be treated as a string, i guess you want the "key" variable to be used instead.

```
var query = { ...this.$route.query };
query[key] = value;
this.$router.push({ query: query });
```

but then i also suspect that you want all key/values in the url? so you'll have to restructure..

```
const settings = this.getSettings();
this.$router.push({ query: { ...this.$route.query, ...settings }});
```